# LineRenderer drawn line is not falling even after applying Rigidbody2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have implemented a feature to draw lines with the help of a mouse and added an edge collider to it. Everything is working fine, but when I added the Rigidbody2D component to the line renderer prefab, and set it to Dynamic, it's not falling down, it is staying at the same position. How do I fix this?

Here's an image:
[image]

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one answered this question, I figured it out! I unticked the `use world space` option and everything works fine. Found this on some random youtube video.